# wrong tmp path ? - imagick

Tags: php, upload, imagick

I am using this code, but is not working correctly. The problem is that exists some issue with `$_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]`

With this code the echo is not showed, but if i remove this line:

```
  $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
```

then, it is showed.

**code**

```
$imagePath = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
$image = new Imagick($imagePath);
echo $imagePath;
// more options
```

**test**

```
var_dump( $imagePath);

string  'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\phpD27C.tmp'
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Then it's porbably failing due to that line. Any errors? Warnings? Do you actually have a class called Imagick?

Comment: @Piskvor i already  tried the imagick class, with a simple shape, and it works. The problem is only when i use `$_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Imagick` class is throwing a fatal error. Turn on error reporting with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```